# Reputation History Showing 0 Rep Log, Instead Nothing Should Be Shown

Tags: feature-request, reputation, accepted-answer, self-answer

I noticed this in the reputation history page. Yesterday I created an answer for my own question and accepted it as the correct answer and didn't do anything else for the day.

I noticed today that it has reported in the reputation history page as

[image]

You don't get any reputation for accepting your own answer however you do for accepting someone elses so I can understand where this history log came from.

I'm pretty sure that the history shouldn't have this logged as there never was any reputation change to begin with. Accepting an answer is already logged in the activity history so this doesn't need to be here.

Comment: The same thing happens when someone removes a question they got votes on and they did nothing else that day. It shows 0 rep with an empty dropdown.

Answer (score 3):

Other zero-rep actions (downvoting a question or upvoting anything) aren't shown on the "reputation" tab of the user page.

To be consistent, self-accepts shouldn't be either.

You can track accepts using the "accepts" filter of the "activity" tab, so the information is still available elsewhere.

Comment: The user drop-down menu show zero-point gains.

Comment: It shows only actions that could have yielded rep if you weren't at the cap, or actions that never yield rep? Also, not what we're talking about here.

Comment: As far as I remember, the drop-down menu shown 0 for a self-accepted answer. I know that is not the same thing; I am just saying that zero-reputation gains are already shown from SE software. As a matter of being consistent, there would not be consistence as long as the drop-down menu shows events for which the user didn't get reputation.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Gotcha. It doesn't stand out as much to me as out of place, because the drop-down shows an amalgam of info shown on different tabs of the user page. It is shown in the list with other reputation-related events, but it just doesn't feel as out of place.